# android how to search item of listview in edittext when getting from csv file?

Tags: android, listview, csv

I am new in Android and developing Quiz application.Here search functionality in quiz.I already get data from csv file.but now i want to search terminology from the list view.I get all the data.but my problem when I search in edit text I cant get any item from list view.Can anyone help me?Thanks in advance.Here is my code

Answer (score 0):

you have to search element in the Arraylist or the array which you set in the adapter you can search an element in arralist like

```
yourArrayList.contains("any data");
```